# How to access parent page controls in child page(User control)in windows metro apps?

Tags: windows-8

I need to access the mainpage values in usercontrols (child page) in windows 8 metro apps.Please let me know how to do this?

In child page i am trying to access the mainpage controls like this :

```
 DealersPage main = new DealersPage();

            Grid grd = main.FindName("visibleGrid") as Grid;
            grd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

But no luck !!!Please tell me

EDIT:In Child Page(usercontrol) on image tapped event i wrote below code.

```
 private void imgClose_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            DealersPage main = this.Parent as DealersPage;
            if (main != null)
            {
                Grid grd = main.FindName("visibleGrid") as Grid;
                grd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            settingsControl.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
```

in MainPage (DealersPage) my design like this:

```
 <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="758" Margin="0,10,0,0"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1366"  x:Name="visibleGrid" Opacity="0.85" Background="#FF858585">
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="600" Margin="454,108,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="500" x:Name="gridpopup">
                <local:Settings x:Name="SettingsUsercontrol"  Visibility="Collapsed"  Height="600" Width="500"/>
</Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: What you've tries so far ? Show some code.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, you are **NOT** actually accessing the main page control in which the user control is present. By using `new DealersPage()` you are actually creating a new instance of the *DealersPage* (your main page) on which `FindName` might return the grid; but that will never be the one that you actually would be looking for.

Your *main* should be something like `(DealersPage)this.Parent` which would be the actual parent page.

**CODE**: Somewhere in your UserControl -

```
DealersPage main = this.Parent as DealersPage;
if(main != null)
{
     Grid grd = main.FindName("visibleGrid") as Grid;
     grd.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
}
```

Comment: i am always getting main as null  in usercontrol.any other changes have to do?

Comment: As long as you have this usercontrol added to that DealersPage, you should be able to get it. Please post your code, along with on which particular action/scenario you are trying to get the grid handle in he user control. This would be of more help.

Comment: Ok. See if you can get your main using _Frame main = Window.Current.Content as Frame;_

Comment: by using frame main=window.current.content as frame then it is ok but getting null value in below line code Grid grd = main.FindName("visibleGrid") as Grid; gettting grd value as null.

Comment: Sorry. I am in commute. Well, isn't it that you should be following MVVM pattern for this and bind a property of your model to the grid Visibility property and should be controlling the value of this property in your user control's View Model (on the respective Command for the image).